# Appearing on the Supported Platforms, Vendors and Partners page

Tags: amp-html, amp-ad

AnyClip appears as a Supported Ad Network on this page -
https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-ad/?format=websites

How can AnyClip also appear in the Ads section on the following page where it does not appear today?
https://amp.dev/support/faq/platform-and-vendor-partners/

Answer (score 0):

amp.dev is actually [open source](https://github.com/ampproject/amp.dev)! So you can see for yourself. In this case, they are two different datasets, it was just an oversight. I created a [pull request to fix it](https://github.com/ampproject/amp.dev/pull/5423)